# Expression for 'One who cares about one's social rank'

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, adjectives, phrase-requests, vocabulary

What is a word or expression for someone who cares about what social rank they're in. Someone who wants to have money, something similar to *ambitious*?

*Vain* is not the word I'm looking for.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: An expression that is used a lot in Britain is 'pecking order'. 'He wants a higher place in the pecking order!'

Comment: Related (possible dupe); [More formal synonym of 'snob'](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68281/8019)

Comment: @TimLymington That word comes with a distinct negative connotation with emphasis on its negativity. Ambition is not a crime. :)

Answer (score 8):

***class-conscious***

see [class consciousness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_consciousness) (Wikipedia)

> … used … to refer to the beliefs that a person holds regarding their **social class or economic rank in society**, the structure of their class, and their class interests [emphasis added]

see also:
[social climber](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/social-climber)

> A person who is eager to gain a higher social status. [ODO]

Answer (score 1):

Socialite?

> A **socialite** is a person who has a reputation in society for spending a significant amount of time participating in social activities such as parties and other fashionable events, entertaining guests and being entertained by others of similar standing...
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialite)

Answer (score 0):

One who is **[narcissistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism)** spends a great deal of time caring about their own self-image.  While it origin comes from [Narcissus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_(mythology)), a figure in Greek mythology who fell in love with his reflection in a pool of water, it is more broadly applied to anyone who is *egotistical* about their own appearance, cosmetic or social.

Answer (score 0):

[**Snob**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snob), as defined in Oxford Dictionaries online:

> 1. a person with an exaggerated respect for high social position or
>      wealth who seeks to associate with social superiors and looks down on
>      those regarded as socially inferior.
>      "her mother was a snob and wanted a lawyer as a son-in-law"
> 2. a person who believes that their tastes in a particular area are superior to those of other people.
>          "a musical snob"

Comment: I’m sorry I seem to have been misunderstood. There is still no reference there. Please see the example in the help center. It is expected that there be a text description of the source, such as ODO or Oxford Dictionaries Online in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

A fop - a foolish man who cares about his appearance.