# What's a less offensive way of calling someone a "snob"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I'm writing a speech and my prof said using "literary snob" was too aggressive.

Comment: Related: [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68281/more-formal-synonyms-of-snob].  What synonyms have you found in your research?

Comment: Definitely need clarification as to what "literary snob" means. There are those who pursue high standards for themselves or more widely (elitists); those who look down on those with lowbrow tastes or low standards (the condescending); those who enjoy intellectually challenging pursuits; those who are sticklers for proper grammar (pedants); those who specifically disdain genre literature or some other irrational pet peeve... Try a thesaurus and look up the candidates for their exact meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *highbrow*

> (of literature, art, music, films, or plays) serious and intended for intelligent educated people who know a lot about these forms of art, or (of people) intelligent and knowing a lot about such things
>
> [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/highbrow)

The word does not have the pejorative overtones of *snob*

> a person who respects and likes only people who are of a high social class, and/or a person who has extremely high standards who is not satisfied by the things that ordinary people like:
>
> [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snob)